# I want to know the line number in editText where the cursor is

Tags: qt, qml

I want to know the line number in editText where the cursor is. How do I get that?

I checked the documentation, and there's no
ps:Is the textedit QML,not QTextEdit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`textDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#textDocument-prop) and [`cursorPosition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#cursorPosition-prop) properties in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickTextDocument>
#include <QTextBlock>

class Helper: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE int currentLineNumber(QQuickTextDocument *textDocument, int cursorPosition){
        if(QTextDocument * td = textDocument->textDocument()){
            QTextBlock tb = td->findBlock(cursorPosition);
            return tb.blockNumber();
        }
        return -1;
    }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Helper helper;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("helper", &helper);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    TextEdit{
        id: textEdit
        anchors.fill: parent
        onCursorPositionChanged: function(){
            let line = helper.currentLineNumber(textEdit.textDocument, textEdit.cursorPosition);
            console.log(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the code you provided, but no matter what line the cursor was on, the result always returned 0  
I looked at the TD variable and its "blockCount" attribute says "not ccallable" and says "No symbol $QTextDocument$in current context"

Comment: In addition, td is not a null pointer.

Comment: @高长春 see the complete code.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to create a new project, using the code you provided, and got the expected result.  
I used qmlRegisterType<Helper> in my previous project, and then helper.currentLinenumber (textedit.textDocument, Textedit.cursorPosition) in QML,  Didn't get the expected results.  Excuse me, is it because I used the wrong call method, resulting in the wrong result?

Comment: @高长春 If you have used `qmlRegisterType` then you must create an instance in qml (you must not use `setContextProperty`): `import helper_url` `Helper{id: helper}`. Those problems have nothing to do with your question since it is basic qml. If my demo works then your task will be to implement it in your project, that is no longer my responsibility, bye.

Comment: I found my problem when I set the wrapMode property for textEdit to Textedit.wrap, so I always get line 0.  
In this case, can we get the line number of the cursor?